# Java + Eclipse: Best way to store constants and tune them at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, constants

I'm facing an interesting problem. I'm developing a game in Java and I would like to know the best way to store my constants. There are several points I would like to achieve:

- Class specific (constants enclosed in types where are used or at least divided into categories)
- Runtime tuning of constants (simple `static final` constants will not work due to compile time constant tables).
- No string literals for constant names. I would like to use my IDE to complete constant names for me.
- If possible, external file with key/value pairs would be nice. I will provide a default value in code when the constant is introduced and it might be overridden by the value stored in the external file. An update can be triggered on startup or by a console command (I already have console)

The workflow should be something like this: I'm debugging the running app. I will change some constant (in code or in external file), trigger the update (eclipse hot replace or in-app action) and the constant gets changed immediately.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You appear to be unclear on the concept of a constant. Are you thinking about global parameters or properties?

Comment: You are right. Is more a parameter then a constant. But it bacome a constant when it is tuned to right value.

Comment: If it can change it is not a constant.  Reconsider your wording - you will just confuse others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at some of the approaches devised for dealing with localization and adapt one to your needs.

Here is one from Sapphire...

http://git.eclipse.org/c/sapphire/org.eclipse.sapphire.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.sapphire.modeling/src/org/eclipse/sapphire/LocalizableText.java

The basic idea is that you have some static (but not final fields) with annotations to supply default/initial value. You execute a method during class init that populates these statics by looking first at property files and falling back to the annotation.

It looks like this:

```
public class NumericRangeValidationService
{
    @Text( "{0} is smaller than the minimum allowed value ({1})" )
    private static LocalizableText smallerThanMinimumMessage;

    @Text( "{0} is larger than the maximum allowed value ({1})" )
    private static LocalizableText largerThanMaxiumMessage;

    static
    {
        LocalizableText.init( NumericRangeValidationService.class );
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank's. This is a kind of concept I'm trying right now. The only flaw of this approach is that the static init section might be forgotten. I'm not sure but there is probably no way to avoid it. Too bad there's no annotation constructors.

Answer (score 0):

THe best way to store constants in a big project is to create a separate file with name having constants like eg:  "StackOverflowConstants.java"

Use constants in this file as:-

```
public static final String USERNAME = "STACK";
```

Comment: Please read this part from OP's question: *No string literals for constant names*